# np.rot90() corrupts an opencv image

Tags: python, opencv

When trying to rotate a landscape image to portrait, after applying the rotation, I cannot draw on the image.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
cv2.circle(img1, tuple([10,10]),radius = 3, color = (255,0,0))
```

works fine.

Then I try:

```
img2 = np.rot90(img1,3)
cv2.circle(img2, tuple([10,10]),radius = 3, color = (255,0,0))
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

Looking at `type(img2)` and `img2.dtype` it seems identical to img1.
the dimensions also seem fine (the first two dimensions are flipped, the third stays "3")

BTW: this seems to work. (why?):

```
img2 = np.rot90(img1,3)
img3 = img2.copy()
cv2.circle(img3, tuple([10,10]),radius = 3, color = (255,0,0))
```

Comment: img2.copy() does help... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and never got to the bottom of it. The workaround I used was to do the image rotation/flipping with OpenCV instead, like:

```
# flip image vertically
img = cv2.flip(img, 0)

# flip image horizontally
img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

# transpose image
img = cv2.transpose(img)
```

Note that rotation is equivalent to doing a transpose and a flip.

Answer (score 1):

`np.rot90` isn't quite corrupting the image per se. The reason behind this is because OpenCV cannot work with "views" of numpy arrays. `np.rot90`, as well as several other numpy operations do not actually modify the underlying array, but instead return a modified "view" to the array. This will typically throw the following error with OpenCV ops:

```
Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Operations like `np.rot90(img1)`, `np.fliplr(img1)` , `np.flipud(img1)`, `np.transpose(img1, (1, 0, 2))`, etc all are simply returning views, and will all throw the same above error.

The reason why adding `.copy()` resolves the error is because, when `.copy()` is called on a view, it becomes stored in memory as a new array that is different from the original array. You can actually verify this quite simply:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.choice(256, (50, 100, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
img_r = np.rot90(img)

print(img_r == img)
# False

print(np.shares_memory(img, img_r))
# True

img_r = img_r.copy()
print(np.shares_memory(img, img_r))
# False
```

As you can see, even though `img_r == img` shows `False`, they still share the same memory -- as `img_r` is a view of `img`. But after calling `.copy()`, the view `img_r` becomes its own array and no longer shares memory with the original `img`.